# Displaying a different SKScene Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I am creating an app in sprite kit, and I am trying to load it from a scene that is not the default "GameScene". I have already created a new .sks file titled "Level1" and created a Cocoa Touch Class called "Level1.swift". However, the scene within "Level1.swift" still does not show in the app.

Here is the code for Level1.swift:

```
    import Foundation
    import SpriteKit

    class Level1: SKScene {
    var tile = Tile(tile: SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 320), cornerRadius: 10.0))
var tile2 = Tile(tile: SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 320), cornerRadius: 10.0))
var tile3 = Tile(tile: SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 320), cornerRadius: 10.0))
var tile4 = Tile(tile: SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 320), cornerRadius: 10.0))

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    tile.color = UIColor.green
    tile.maxTileNumberCounter = 4
    tile.tileNumber = 1
    tile.initializeTile()

    tile2.color = UIColor.blue
    tile2.maxTileNumberCounter = 4
    tile2.tileNumber = 2
    tile2.initializeTile()

    tile3.color = UIColor.blue
    tile3.maxTileNumberCounter = 4
    tile3.tileNumber = 3
    tile3.initializeTile()

    tile4.color = UIColor.blue
    tile4.maxTileNumberCounter = 4
    tile4.tileNumber = 4
    tile4.initializeTile()



    self.addChild(tile.tile)
    self.addChild(tile2.tile)
    self.addChild(tile3.tile)
    self.addChild(tile4.tile)
}
```

And here is the code for my viewController:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "Level1") {
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }

        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
    }
}

override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return true
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        return .allButUpsideDown
    } else {
        return .all
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
}
```

Any help in getting this to work would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you put the tile code into the `GameScene.swift` and update GameViewController to load `GameScene` does it work as expected? It is always a good idea to isolate unexpected behaviour!

Comment: did you make sure you defined the custom class to Level1 in the sks file

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @Knight0fDragon. You should check your `Level1.sks` file, set `Custom Class` to `Level1` in `Custom Class` inspector. Here is a [demo](https://github.com/Millionaryearl/Stack-Overflow/tree/master/SceneTest)